# caching & ssl in nginx

Tags: caching, nginx

Trying to get nginx to cache static assets, but getting a 404 on everything. If I take out the cache block it works fine, but obviously it's not caching.  How can I set this up so that things will get cached by nginx?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

upstream backends {
    server 127.0.0.1:8443;
    #server 192.168.100.101:80;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl; # 'ssl' parameter tells NGINX to decrypt the traffic
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt; # The certificate file
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key; # The private key file

     ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        proxy_pass http://backends;
    }


 location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 168h;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nginx` [chooses one location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) block to process a request. You need to replicate or inherit common functionality. For example:

```
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://backends;
}

location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 168h;
    proxy_pass http://backends;
}
```

Replicating complex configurations is best done with a separate file by using the `include` directive.